# Installing windows 7 on mac hardware - how to right click :$

Tags: windows-7, windows, macbook

On a MacBook, I got a new HDD an installed Windows 7 on it and Ubuntu as dual boot.

I can right click in Ubuntu using the 3 fingers gestures - but I can't do that in Windows 7

I know this is a stupid question, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a stupid question.

1. I believe if you click and hold, it will be treated as a right click. Not sure because I don't have the (mis?)fortune of owning any Mac hardware :( (I would, but it's friggin expensive).
2. You could always borrow a plain 2 button mouse for doing the install, and then once the Bootcamp things are installed for the gesture support return that mouse.

Answer (score 2):

From the BootCamp Readme:

> **To right-click using a trackpad:**
>   Place two fingers on the trackpad and click the trackpad button.

Comment: That would work but under osX - i have win7-the mouse will just move and no right click (:

Comment: @mireille Have you installed the apple drivers for Windows that come with BootCamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the keyboard: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>.  Of course, for that to work, you need focus to be on the control or link for which you want to see the content menu, which isn't always possible.  So it depends on what you're right-clicking.

Comment: I figured the Shift F10 part already - but looking for a sane way to right click :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, command-clicking is the old way of right-clicking. Not sure if that continues to hold true in a win7 install on the mac platform though.